Obtain Phonon density of using Lammps
I have a need of obtaining the phonon density of states using lammps MD simulations.
could you please explain the approach(s) with the steps involve it?
Thanks

I happen to have a blog talking about velocity auto-correlation functions (that can be obtained from MD simulations) and phonon DOS: https://chengcheng-xiao.github.io/post/2021/08/20/Correlation_to_phonon_DOS.html. If you find this usefull I can summarize it and put it into an answer;)

@ChengchengXiao 's answer is very good, so I have very little to add. Back when I was learning this stuff, I looked here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282734/phonon-density-of-states-from-velocity-autocorrelation-function .  Regarding calculating vacf: you can do it as a post processing step or use a fix in lammps. See here: https://docs.lammps.org/compute_vacf.html . Cheers!

Thanks a lot!!!
